# Where to place regex functions in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a lot of regex functions that validates the data.

They have a common domain. Where to place them, in service, helper wherelse?
As I know to place it in controller is not good idea, because it is not reusable.

Comment: Helpers maybe..

Comment: If the regex functions are specific to validation, it seems [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) might be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex are more close to utility functions. In fact, utilities methods can be used anywhere depending upon the requirements. Therefor, these must be independent to any entity/models, controller or any class in Laravel.

Further, your question is closely connected with software engineering concept known as **Coupling vs Cohesion**

**Coupling** is defined as the degree of interdependence between the modules and **Cohesion** is defined as the degree of relationship between elements of the same module.

So a good software design says that there must always be **low coupling** and **high cohesion**.

Therefor, I believe if we create **Regex utility** module then it should work independently of any module/class/model/controller. They must have least dependency between each other to have **low coupling** as much as possible. Chances are higher that **methods** you define in **Regex module** will reuse across the other controllers/classes.

On the other hand, if you define **Regex related methods** inside controller or a model, then their inter module dependency will increase and chances are we will not be able to **reuse these regex** related methods anymore.

**Therefor**, a good idea is to isolate modules from each other that have no particular dependency and will reuse across the other modules.

In Laravel, we generally create **Helper class/methods** to achieve this. So you can defiantly go with **Helper classes** approach. Create a **Regex Helper** class and reuse it in whole application.

Cheers :)